# How get process that is locking Database on SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, error-handling, multi-thread

I'm developing a iOS app using SQLite. I've got a class to manage SQL's operations, basically read, write and update. In many cases I get a `SQLITE_BUSY` error, so I want know which process is using the database at the moment that the `SQLITE_BUSY` error occurs. I believe that I'm trying to `INSERT` data while another process is reading data.

Actually I'm trying handle it like this: (YES, IT'S WRONG)

```
    let aux_error_code = 0
    repeat {
        if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            lastid = Int(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db))
            aux_error_code = 0
        } else {
            aux_error_code = sqlite3_errcode(db)
            print("ERRO SQLITE INSERT STEP, ERROR CODE: \(aux_error_code), MSG ERROR: \(sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)\n QUERY: \(insertStatementString)")
        }
    } while(aux_error_code == 5)
```

This generate a big list of prints.

SQLite has some ways to handle this, but to choose one I want know what process specifically is causing this problem. 
I believe that this is a good way to solve my problem: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html, but I don't have experience with this. Because that I want know which process causes my problem, if is read or update, or insert by other function too. Anyone can help me to handle this?

Comment: I'd guess that your app is the only one that accesses this database file. You have an active transaction in some other connection.